# Tikz-qtree label alignment issue

Tags: tikz-qtree

Is there anyway I can obtain that those labels get correct vertical alignment ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}} % Allows including labels as parts of the terminal node, by using \\.

\begin{document}
\tikzset{level 2/.style={level distance=50pt}}
\Tree
    [.Manners [.{Eventualities\\{[}+ quantized{]}} 
        [.{Events\\{[}+ dynamic{]}} ][.{Stages\\{[}-- dynamic{]}} ] ][.{Tropes\\{[}-- quantized{]}}
            [.Results ][.Qualities ] ] ]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have just discovered `forest` and it appears to be a far superior package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}

    \begin{forest}
        [Manners
           [Eventualities\\{[}+ quantized{]}
            [Events\\{[}+ dynamic{]}][Stages\\{[}-- dynamic{]}]]
        [Tropes\\ {[}-- quantized{]}
           [Results][Qualities]]]
    \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, `forest` is by far a superior package for trees.

Comment: And surprisingly easy to use.